# append html in body of currently oppened tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to append html in body of currently openned tab. when i put my code in background js it append the html in background.html and when i use same code in poPup js it append it on poPup.hmtl.  i want myDiv to be append to currently openned tab html.  there is code that m using

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+ r +","+ g +","+ b +")";
myDiv.style.position        = "fixed";
myDiv.style.width           = "500px";
myDiv.style.height          = 200 + "px";
myDiv.style.top             = 200 + "px";
myDiv.innerHTML = "hi this is test";
Document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(myDiv);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should inject a content script into the currently opened tab and run your code from there.

Comment: i have shift my code to detect.js file but it again appending the div in background.html

Comment: now i got what i wanted to do. I more thing i do in background.js file load content script to all oppened tabs.

chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function(tabs){
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: 'jquery-1.7.1.min.js'}); 
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {file: 'detect.js'});                         
        }
    });